# Sequelize .update() not using the correct where and updates all rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create an approval command.
Everything about it, should be working, but it never works correctly.
I've changed my Database to have "id" first, but it still prefers to update on "user" instead.

I've tried having my code just be; but that never worked out. Even though I use it everywhere else.

```
await ticketApproval.update({status: 1});
```

I've checked documentation and other StackOverflow questions and answers.
Nothing has worked yet, but from what I can tell, nothing in my code should be telling it to update on the **"user"** id. Since I only ever tell it to search on the ticket **"id"** and **"server"** id
It feels like it's just outright ignoring the Where.

**Code**
[image: Code]

**Console**
[image]

**Test Sample**
[image]

Comment: Please don't post pieces of code as images. It's hard to use them or modify them in answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You clearly confuse the `update` method of a record instance with the static `update` of a model.
Only static `update` has the `where` option because it updates several records in DB using passed conditions in contrast to the instance `update` method that uses a primary key value of a certain record to update it with passed values.
Compare:

```js
// here we have a model instance for a concrete record
const ticketApproval = await Ticket.findOne({
  where: {
     id: ticketToApprove
  }
})
// by calling the instance `update` we always update this concrete record only
// using a primary key value condition, see a primary key field defined in a model
await ticketApproval.update({ status: 1 });
```

with

```js
// by calling the static `update` we update all records that satisfy the indicated conditions
await Ticket.update({ status: 1 }, {
  where: {
     id: ticketToApprove
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm not very sure about it, but I've tried `await ticketApproval.update({ status: 1 });` It was actually the first thing I used, since it's how I've handled everything before, but that was still updating on the user id, instead of the ticket id.

I even removed the server id and still have the same issue. I also use it, since I want to make sure people aren't approving tickets outside of that server. I guess I could also just make an if statement for that.

Comment: `ticketApproval` is an instance of the `concrete` record and thus its `update` method will always update this only record using a primary key field and its value in WHERE condition

Comment: If you wish to update several records indicating conditions in `where` option just update the static `Ticket.update` method

Comment: That's the problem, regardless if I use `ticketApproval.update({ status: 1 });` It still updates on user. I can't find what is causing it to update on user, since it seems to be disregarding the options for the "where"

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll just use the Where on `Ticket.update` instead, since that actually works for me

Comment: This call `ticketApproval.update({ status: 1 }` is equal to something like this: `UPDATE ticket SET status=1 WHERE userId = <primary key value>`. This call `Ticket.update({ status: 1}, { where: { userId: 1, server: 2 } })` is equal to `UPDATE ticket SET status=1 WHERE userId = 1 AND server=2`